# Old STM32 eclipse project to VSCode

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, debugging, stm32

I found an old eclipse project for a STM32F4 nucleo board. I would like to migrate it to vscode.
Host OS is Ubuntu 22.04 and I'm new to vscode.
The project is build in a docker container. That works so far. The next step is to debug the code. I was able to set up the launch.json using openOCD. Debug session starts and stops at breakpoint as expected. So far so good.
The problem: when the debug session reaches the breakpoint, it cannot show the file (main.c) where the breakpoint is located:

[image]

It points to the file using completely wrong path (at least it seems to me):

[image]

the correct path is /Home/username/Testbench..
Here is the folder structure in vscode:

[image]

here is my launch.json:

```
    {

    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.

    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.

    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387

    "version": "0.2.0",

    "configurations": [

        {

            "type": "cortex-debug",

            "request": "launch",

            "name": "Debug (OpenOCD)",

            "servertype": "openocd",

            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",

            "runToEntryPoint": "main",

            "executable": "./artifacts/Testbench.elf",

            "device": "STM32F401RE",

            "configFiles": [

                "interface/stlink-dap.cfg",

                "target/stm32f4x.cfg"

            ],

            "showDevDebugOutput": "none",

        }

    ]

}
```

and my c_cpp_configuration.json

```
    {

  "env": {

    "myIncludePath": ["${workspaceFolder}/APP"],

    "myDefines": ["DEBUG", "MY_FEATURE=1"]

  },

    "configurations": [

      {

        "name": "Linux",

        "includePath": ["${workspaceFolder}/**"],

        "defines": [],

        "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",

        "cStandard": "c11",

        "cppStandard": "c++17",

        "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64"

      }

    ],

    "version": 4

  }
```

What am I missing here?